# C++ What is my own file name?

Tags: c++, variables, system

I have a piece of C++ code that calls the system command.. I want to pass the file name of my own C++ executable to the system command.. anyone know how to do this? 
So for example my C++ code is called "switch-5".. what I want to do is something like;

system("./script.sh switch-5");

Anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your executable name is the first argument passed in argv.

To test this just run:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   printf("My program name: '%s'\n", argv[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

(I am assuming you know how to combine it with your script name to get the string to pass to system().)

Comment: If you have put the executable on your path and are therefore able to call it without a real path specifier, then only the base name that you used to call it will be in argv[0]. So if you want to do stuff like find a file relative to the executable you'll have to find a different way.

Answer (score 0):

`argv[0]` as passed to main is the name of your executable.

Comment: While `argv[0]` tends to be the name of executable, my understanding is that it's a convention and not guaranteed...

Comment: @rueben: You may be right.  But I believe when it is not, it's because the program modified it.  IIRC some of the programs in SAMBA do this to avoid leaking passwords in /proc and the output from ps.

Comment: There's more background here on the full story: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383973/is-args0-guaranteed-to-be-the-path-of-execution

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a global variable during app startup:

```
static char *selfname;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    selfname = argv[0];

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware, argv[0] contains exactly what was used to start the program, including relative or absolute path, for example: "./programname".