# xcode argv[0] is the path name instead of the first argument

Tags: c++, xcode

`argv[0]` in my c++ program shows `:/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project4/Build/Products/Debug/project4`

Instead of the first argument I enter to it. Can I change this?

Comment: This is correct and by definition. There is no way to change it.

Comment: Which is correct. That's it.

Comment: If you want the first supplied argument use `argv[1]`

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383973/is-args0-guaranteed-to-be-the-path-of-execution

Answer (score 2):

The C programming system RELIES on `argv[0]` containing the name of the program itself (with or without path, depending on the system you use). Many programs depend on that to find the path where the program lives, for example.

Your first argument will be in `argv[1]`, and the last one at `argv[argc-1]`.

In other words:

```
 /usr/bin/myprog foo bar baz
```

will have

```
 argc = 4
 argv[0] = /usr/bin/myprog
 argv[1] = foo
 argv[2] = bar
 argv[3] = baz
```

If this wasn't followed, all standard programs would go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can :-) Use this:

```
argv[0] = argv[1];
```

And you will get first argument in `argv[0]`.

But don't do this in real programs, please.

Comment: You would have to do `for(i = argc - 1; i >= 1; i--) argv[i-1] = argv[i];` tho', if there is more than 1 argument.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Formally, no. OP wants only that first argument will be in `argv[0]`, and nothing more ;-).

Comment: At this precise moment in time, perhaps... :)